# Why does the button look like more larger when I set density=hdpi?

Tags: android

I use emulator to display a android app and set density = mdpi.  After change the density from mdpi to hdpi,I think the button look like small size, but in actual the button look like more larger when I set density=hdpi, why? Thanks!

density=mdpi: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209352/low.PNG
density=hdpi: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209352/High.PNG
Settings: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209352/set.PNG

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >        

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerMsgFolder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"   
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"   
            android:paddingLeft="8dip"  
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTotalTitle"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/spinnerMsgFolder"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spinnerMsgFolder"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="8dip"
            android:text="@string/totalAndSelectedTitle" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTotalValue"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/spinnerMsgFolder"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textTotalTitle"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="6dip"
            android:paddingBottom="8dip"
            android:text="0/1" >
        </TextView>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chAll"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/spinnerMsgFolder"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"           
             />

    </RelativeLayout> 



    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:background="#DDDDDD"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnToEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="To Email" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edit"
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnToEmail"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Test" >
        </TextView>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Exit" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What other settings are you changing besides pixel density? If you don't change the physical size or pixel count, the pixel density can't actually change.

Comment: I change only density at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209352/set.PNG

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you aren't increasing your pixel count when you change the density. The resource system will scale up all dimensions specified with "dip" or "dp". (By the way, "dip" is deprecated -- you should use "dp" instead).

If you had two real devices that were exactly the same size in inches, but one was mdpi and the other hdpi, the number of pixels would be increased, but the buttons would be exactly the same size because of the automatic scaling. If you specify dimensions in "px", then this scaling will not happen, and the higher density screen will display buttons smaller, as you inferred above.

Comment: Thanks! So I feel it is very strange, Start_High.PNG is a start screen of emulator when set density=hdpi, and both the text and the button are larger,
Start_Low.PNG is a start screen of emulator when set density=mdpi, but both the text and the button are small, why?
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209352/Start_High.PNG
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209352/Start_Low.PNG

Comment: Think about it, you're saying that the device display is denser but has the same resolution, so android makes everything *bigger* so they retain the same size *in the actual devices*. What's confusing you is that you are running this in an emulator and the density does not actually change (that's defined by your monitor).

Comment: Note that a 4 inch device with hdpi and 400x600 is highly unlikely. You might want to research actual device combinations (or use some of the provided ones) instead of creating ones that don't really make any sense.